# Removing a Icon/Button That shares class names with Multiple other Dom elements

Tags: css, angular

On the Angular Calendar there is this silly Event icon on the bottom left of every day
Im trying to be rid of it, But it shares a class name with the day blocks so I cant just Say Pointer-event:none;

cause then I cant expand the events on the days

```
<div class="cal-events ng-star-inserted"><div mwldraggable="" dragactiveclass="cal-drag-active" class="cal-event Marks ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-drag-active-class="cal-drag-active" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-ng-class="Marks" ng-reflect-contents="Test1 Marks" ng-reflect-placement="auto" ng-reflect-event="[object Object]" ng-reflect-append-to-body="true" ng-reflect-drop-data="[object Object]" ng-reflect-drag-axis="[object Object]" ng-reflect-validate-drag="function isWithinThreshold({ x" ng-reflect-touch-start-long-press="[object Object]" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color: rgb(204, 51, 51);"></div><!--container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-track-by": "(index, event) => event.id ? e"
}--></div>
```

The class names it shares is "cal-events ng-start-insterted"

Now I dont know how to share this to well as its generated Dom elements So i can just give u my layout for it..

But Maybe the image describes the issue a bit better
[image]

Now I know this qeustion is a rough ask If i can improve it let me know: But as I mentioned its generated code I dont know how to show this to you, Besides telling u that The day blocks and that dot share the same classes but I dont want the dot to be interactive but I want the blocks to be

Comment: You could target based on its position in the DOM. For example, if it's the first or nth child of a known element you could target the class only if it's where you expect it https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp. Also, be careful about encapsulation if you have it switched on...

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Sadly I did try that, It just removes the pointer event from the Days blocks as well

Comment: Can you post a Stackblitz or similar and I can take a look?

Comment: Actually ya tbh 
https://angular-calendar.com/#/kitchen-sink
Would be your best bet its the exact same Html layout as im using granted ive changed some things but its all done on the backend

Comment: `mwl-calendar-month-cell .cal-events { display: none;
}` seems like it should work without targeting the days sections

Comment: Your Stackblitz link doesn't work. You'll need to use the share button

Comment: Apologies here u go https://stackblitz.com/edit/aetbma--run?file= 

Its the Calendar general demo one but as I mentioned its all the same, Hmm. seems to hide the actual event accordion but disables the button aswell but it still displays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info you posted, it looks like you will need to target based on this being inside a parent element that is specific only to the month view. Something like this:

```
mwl-calendar-month-cell .cal-events { display: none; }
```

Since in the example you post the days block (I'm assuming you mean what you see when you click the 'Days' button) does not have the `mwl-calendar-month-cell` wrapper element around its events, this should avoid your problem with it hiding elements you don't want it to.

Comment: Ah it does actually remove it I think the button not working is something els I did Thanks a mil || Edit: It was something I did